# Not able to get the android property of my view in nativescript

Tags: android, nativescript

I am trying to make a fullscreen android app using this tutorial:
https://bradmartin.net/2016/03/10/fullscreen-and-navigation-bar-color-in-a-nativescript-android-app/

Everything is going fine except the part where I would set the padding of the first view on the page so it wouldn't go behind the status bar.
but at this line:

```
var lab = page.getViewById("btn").android;
```

The lab variable is undefined. I have checked the id and it is fine.since I can access the baseview (without the android property).
I have checked the docs and android property is there but here I get an undefined. I am also running on a physical android device.

Comment: When exactly you are executing this line of code? `loaded` event is usually the best place to access `.android` as that ensures the native view is created.

Comment: are you writing code inside ` function pageLoaded(args) ` ? What exactly do you need separate styles for Android and IOS ?? if so use componentname.component.ios.scss & componentname.component.android.scss